# Click event not bubbling when image clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="tgt"><img src="http://placehold.it/48x48" width="48px" height="48px"></li>
    <li class="tgt"><img src="http://placehold.it/48x48" width="48px" height="48px"></li>
    <li class="tgt"><img src="http://placehold.it/48x48" width="48px" height="48px"></li>
</ul>
```

Code from the fiddle:

```
$('.tgt').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('tgt')) {
        $(e.target).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I attach a click handler using jquery's event delegation to all .tgt elements. For some reason, if I click on the image, the event does not bubble up to the li. Instead the event target is revealed to be the image.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CgC4V/

Why is the event not bubbling up to li.tgt?

Comment: It is best to put some key parts of your code on this page so someone could answer it if their firewall doesn't allow access to jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you clicking on the image or on the bullet in front of the <li>?

Comment: i hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CgC4V/5/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The event *is* bubbling up, but the *target* element that you are testing with `e.target` is the element that was actually clicked as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CgC4V/1/

That is the way that event bubbling is supposed to work - if the event didn't bubble your handler attached to the li elements would not be triggered.

You can use `this` to refer to the li that was clicked:

```
$('.tgt').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('tgt')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

You probably don't need to test whether the element has the `tgt` class though, because you already know it must be one of the li elements that originally had that class.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CgC4V/3/

UPDATE for the comments:

> *"Should I then be accessing jquery.event.currentTarget instead? What about in cases where the context is not the jquery element. What property of jQuery.event has a reference to the correct element?"*

Yes, [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) will give you the correct element. "Normally", and for the code you've shown, `event.currentTarget` would be the same as `this`, but if you were to do something to alter the value of `this` (e.g., if you've used `$.proxy()` or [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) then `event.currentTarget` will give you the right element.

Note also that sometimes `event.currentTarget` will be the same element as `event.target` (and `this` if you've not altered `this`) - in your example if you click the "dot" of the li element rather than the image then the target is the li itself.

Comment: Should I then be accessing jquery.event.currentTarget instead?

Comment: @Adam - You can just use `this`.

Comment: What about in cases where the context is not the jquery element. What property of jQuery.event has a reference to the correct element?

Comment: Do you think the code here is complicated? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8U3cX/

Comment: @Omar - it's not complicated in the sense of being difficult to understand, but it is more complicated than necessary to solve the OP's problem. There's no need to handle clicks on the images directly when those click events bubble up.

Comment: I thought he wanted to attach event to imgs as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).parent('li').hasClass('tgt')) {
        $(e.target).parent('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

This will make the `img` the actual target but still provide the highlighting for the entire list item.

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic solution so if the tag names were to change, I wouldn't be dependent on that.

Answer (score 1):

e refers to the event, but you want to add the class when the obj is clicked, so just change $(e.target) to $(this) and it should work:

```
$('.tgt').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('tgt')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `$(this)` instead of `event.target`, because `$(this)` will always be the `<li>` itself, where `event.target` will point to the image if the image is the deepest available element in the DOM that received a click event.

[**See this demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CgC4V/4/)

```
$('.tgt').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('tgt')) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**Edit for clarification:** Consider the results below.

When the **`<li>`** is clicked, and **not** the `<img>`:

- `$(this)` points to the `<li>`
- `event.target` points to the `<li>`

When the **`<img>`** is clicked:

- `$(this)` points to the `<li>`
- `event.target` points to the `<img>`

This is because, of all elements that receive a click event, `event.target` will always point to the one that is deepest in the DOM. `$(this)`, however, will always sit on the `<li>` and will catch any events that bubble up from the clicked `<img>`.